# Supabase & SvelteKit Auth Error when registering a new user "PKCE flow"

Tags: sveltekit, supabase

Whenever I try to register a new account I get the following error on my container:

```
PKCE flow is not supported on signups with autoconfirm enabled
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to roll back the supabase sveltekit helper. I did the following:

Changed the version inside of my package.json to this

> "@supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit": "^0.9.4",

Then in the terminal run `pnpm i` or `npm install`

**version 0.10.0 causes this error**

If you are reading this and the error is gone, please let us know! Thanks!